# Unable to install catboost in R

Tags: r, catboost

I'm facing trouble downloading `catboost` in R.
Kindly help to resolve this issue,

```
> install.packages('catboost')
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Rishabh Ojha/Documents/R/win-library/3.5’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘catboost’ is not available (for R version 3.5.2)
```

My version is as follows:

```
> version

platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          5.2                         
year           2018                        
month          12                          
day            20                          
svn rev        75870                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)
nickname       Eggshell Igloo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is pretty self-explanatory. `catboost` is *not* available from CRAN (but see e.g. [here](https://github.com/catboost/catboost/issues/439) for a discussion).

You *can* however install `catboost` if you follow the installation guide available from the [`catboost` GitHub project site](https://github.com/catboost/catboost). Specifically, the installation instructions for installing `catboost` on a Windows machine can be found on [Install from a local copy on Windows](https://tech.yandex.com/catboost/doc/dg/installation/r-installation-local-copy-installation-windows-docpage/#r-installation-local-copy-installation-windows).

From the latter link:

> - It is strongly recommended to install the released version. Try it if other installation methods result in errors.
> - Windows installation currently requires Visual C++ 2017 Build Tools.
> - Training on GPU requires NVIDIA Driver of version 390.xx or higher.

It's probably also worth taking a look at the project's GitHub issues, e.g. [Building and installing problem in R](https://github.com/catboost/catboost/issues/301). Good luck.